# angular controllers is not a function

Tags: angularjs

just for learning purpose--

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script src="ctrl.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="abc">
      <h1 ng-controller="ctrl">{{data}}</h1>
    </body>

    </html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('abc', []);
```

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('abc').controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.data="hello";
});
```

[js fiddle link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDULb2xMzmc6wtdwTtUj?p=preview)
it showing error... what i ve done wrong here???

Comment: In your demo the file ctrl.js is actually named cntrl.js. If you fix that, the demo works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your controller file wrongly.

```
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="cntrl.js"></script>
</head>
```